# Create user via API in KeyCloak without admin-cli?

Tags: keycloak

Imagine a realm `my-realm` and client `my-client` were created.
Is it possible to create users via API without admin-cli (with secret of `my-client` client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `admin_cli` is one of default client. It has the `Direct Access Grant`.
It means user can get the access token to use it for `client_id` parameter when the get access toke (POST) call.

```
grant_type=password - This tells the server you’re using the Password grant type
username= - The user’s username that they entered in the application
password= - The user’s password that they entered in the application
client_id= - The public identifier of the application that the developer obtained during registration
client_secret= - (optional) - If the application is a “confidential client”
```

If you made your own client(example: my-client) and it has `Direct Access Grant`, you can using that instead of `admin-cli`.

This is `admin-cli`'s grant_type image.

[image]

The `password` grant_type is one of the simplest OAuth grants and involves only one step

You can see other grant_types too in [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749)

**client_credentials**, **authorization_code**, **refresh_token**